# Using jQuery $(this).addClass() breaks working code

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm creating a form where an error message appears when the input loses focus if the input is empty. I also want to add a class to the input to give it a red border.

The problem arises when I add `$(this).addClass("error");` - the error message no longer shows. Does using `addClass()` change the reference of `this` within the function? Can anybody explain to me what is happening? I'm usually pretty good with jQuery but I'm a bit lost here.

Here's my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.showError = function(error) {
    $(this).addClass("error");
    $errorElement = this.closest(".input-field").find(".error");
    if (!$errorElement.length) {
      $errorElement = $('<span class="error"></span>').appendTo(this.closest(".input-field"));
    }
    $errorElement.text(this.data("errormsg"));
  };

  $("input").on("focusout", function(e) {
    $(this).showError();
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" data-errormsg="Please enter your first name" />
</div>
```

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it works absolutely fine. Check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I constantly have the console open, nothing shows.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing for anyone to debug unless you can show us your non-working logic

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Give the question another read - there should be an error message displayed along with the red border. It shows fine when the `addClass()` line is not present.

Comment: That's because you've created a `.error` element. Therefore your `if (!$errorElement.length)` condition no longer matches for the error message to be appended. If you want both to happen you need to amend the logic. It has nothing to do with the scope of `this` being changed (which it isn't)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Now that makes much more sense! :D I'm an idiot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$errorElement = this.closest(".input-field").find(".error");
```

Since you just added `error` to the input, this line finds the input and adds the text to it, however since an input element has no children, the text isn't shown. Use

```
$errorElement = this.closest(".input-field").find("span.error");
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! Thanks I'll accept the answer when I can.

Comment: @GlennFerrie just for you.